# how to isolate the first and the second number without a string method(java school project)

Tags: java

In my school project the teacher asked that we don't use any string method but I need to isolate the first number and the second number. The number will be from 6 to 9 digit long.

The small program take the model code of a product and decompose it. The fist number will be associate with a categories(c), the second one with a product(p) within this categories and the rest will be printed as the model number.

Do you have any idea how to make it happen?

This is the full program:

```
 public class GestionCodesProduits {

/**
 *
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    //CONSTANTE
    final String MSG_PRESENTATION = "Ce programme permet de creer des codes de produits electroniques\n"
        + "et d'afficher l'information sur un produit selon son code\n\n\n";

    final String MSG_MENU_PRINCIPAL = "----\nMENU\n----\n\n1.Construire un code produit\n2.Afficher les informations sur un produit"
        + "\n3.Quitter\n\nEntrez votre choix (1,2 ou 3) : ";

    final String MSG_CATEGORIES = "----------\nCATEGORIES\n----------\n\nSelectionner type de produit:\n"
        + "1.Ordinateurs\n2.Televiseurs\n3.Appareils photo\n4.Petits electros\n\n\n"
        + "Entrez le numero de categorie du produit : ";

    final String MSG_MENU_ORDI = "--------\nPRODUITS : \n--------\n\n1.Ordinateur de bureau\n2.Portable\n3.Tablette"
        + "\n4.Moniteur\n5.Imprimante/Numerisateur"
        + "\n\nEntrez le numero du produit : ";

    final String MSG_MENU_TELE = "--------\nPRODUITS : \n--------\n\n1.Televiseur\n2.Projecteur"
        + "\n\nEntrez le numero du produit : ";

    final String MSG_MENU_PELECTROS = "--------\nPRODUITS : \n--------\n\n1.Cafetiere\n2.Robot culinaire\n3.Melangeur\n4.Batteur"
        + "\n5.Friteuse/Grill\n6.Grille-Pain/Four Grille-Pain"
        + "\n\nEntrez le numero du produit : ";

    final String MSG_INFO_CATEGORIES = "CATEGORIE : ";
    final String MSG_INFO_PRODUIT = "PRODUIT : ";
    final String MSG_INFO_NUM_MODELE = "NUMERO DE MODELE :";

    final String MSG_END_PROGRAM = "\n\nFIN NORMALE DU PROGRAMME";
    final String MSG_PRODUCT_CODE = "ENTREZ LE CODE DU PRODUIT : ";
    final String MSG_NUM_MODELE = "Entree numero de modele : ";
    final String MSG_RETOUR = "Appuyez sur <ENTREE> pour revenir au menu...";

    final String MSG_ERR_MENU = "\nErreur ! Vous devez entrer 1, 2 (ou 3 pour quitter). \nRecommencez...";        
    final String MSG_ERR_CATEGORIES = "\nErreur ! Entrez un numero entre 1 et 4. \nRecommencez...";        
    final String MSG_ERR_ORDI = "\nErreur ! Entrez un numero entre 1 et 5. \nRecommencez...";  
    final String MSG_ERR_TELE = "\nErreur ! Entrez un numero entre 1 et 2. \nRecommencez...";
    final String MSG_ERR_PELECTRO = "\nErreur ! Entrez un numero entre 1 et 6. \nRecommencez...";
    final String MSG_ERR_NUM_MODELE = "\nErreur ! Le numero du modele est invalide. \nRecommencez...";
    final String MSG_ERR_CODE = "*** Ce code de produit est invalide ***";

    //VARIABLE

    char selectionMenuPrincipal;

    char selectionCategories;

    char selectionProduits;        

    int selectionNumModele;

    int codeProduit;
    // AFFICHAGE MENU PRESENTATION
    System.out.println(MSG_PRESENTATION);

    //AFFICHAGE MENU PRINCIPAL
    do {
        System.out.print(MSG_MENU_PRINCIPAL);
        selectionMenuPrincipal = Clavier.lireCharLn();

        while (selectionMenuPrincipal < '1' || selectionMenuPrincipal > '3') {
            System.out.print(MSG_ERR_MENU);
            selectionMenuPrincipal = Clavier.lireCharLn();
        }

        //AFFICHAGE MENU CATEGORIES
        if (selectionMenuPrincipal == '1') {
            System.out.print(MSG_CATEGORIES);
            selectionCategories = Clavier.lireCharLn();

            //VALIDATION DE LA SELECTION CATEGORIE
            while (selectionCategories < '1' || selectionCategories > '4') {
                System.out.println(MSG_ERR_CATEGORIES);
                selectionCategories = Clavier.lireCharLn();
            }

            //SELECTION DE LA CATEGORIE
            if (selectionCategories == '1') {
                System.out.print(MSG_MENU_ORDI);
                selectionProduits = Clavier.lireCharLn();
                System.out.print(MSG_NUM_MODELE);
                selectionNumModele = Clavier.lireInt();

                //VALIDATION DU NUMERO DE MODELE
                while (selectionNumModele < 1000 || selectionNumModele > 9999999) {
                    System.out.println(MSG_ERR_NUM_MODELE);
                    selectionNumModele = Clavier.lireInt();
                }
                System.out.println("CODE DE PRODUIT : " + selectionCategories + selectionProduits + selectionNumModele);
                System.out.print(MSG_RETOUR);
                Clavier.lireFinLigne();

            }else if (selectionCategories == '2') {
                System.out.print(MSG_MENU_TELE);
                selectionProduits = Clavier.lireChar();
                System.out.print(MSG_NUM_MODELE);
                selectionNumModele = Clavier.lireInt();

                //VALIDATION DU NUMERO DE MODELE
                while (selectionNumModele < 1000 || selectionNumModele >= 9999999) {
                    System.out.println(MSG_ERR_NUM_MODELE);
                    selectionNumModele = Clavier.lireInt();
                }
                System.out.println("CODE DE PRODUIT : " + selectionCategories + selectionProduits + selectionNumModele);
                System.out.print(MSG_RETOUR);
                Clavier.lireFinLigne();

            }else if (selectionCategories == '3') {
                System.out.print(MSG_NUM_MODELE);
                selectionNumModele = Clavier.lireInt();

                //VALIDATION DU NUMERO DE MODELE
                while (selectionNumModele < 1000 || selectionNumModele >= 9999999) {
                    System.out.println(MSG_ERR_NUM_MODELE);
                    selectionNumModele = Clavier.lireInt();
                }
                System.out.println("CODE DE PRODUIT : " + selectionCategories + selectionNumModele);
                System.out.print(MSG_RETOUR);
                Clavier.lireFinLigne();

            }else if (selectionCategories == '4') {
                System.out.print(MSG_MENU_PELECTROS);
                selectionProduits = Clavier.lireChar();
                System.out.print(MSG_NUM_MODELE);
                selectionNumModele = Clavier.lireInt();

                //VALIDATION DU NUMERO DE MODELE
                while (selectionNumModele < 1000 || selectionNumModele > 9999999) {
                    System.out.print(MSG_ERR_NUM_MODELE);
                    selectionNumModele = Clavier.lireInt();
                }
                System.out.println("CODE DE PRODUIT : " + selectionCategories + selectionProduits + selectionNumModele);
                System.out.print(MSG_RETOUR);
                Clavier.lireFinLigne();

            }

            //AFFICHAGE DU MENU D'INFORMATION DE CODE DE PRODUIT
        }else if (selectionMenuPrincipal == '2') {
            System.out.print(MSG_PRODUCT_CODE);
            codeProduit = Clavier.lireInt();
            while (codeProduit < 100000 || codeProduit > 999999999) {
                System.out.print(MSG_ERR_CODE);
                codeProduit = Clavier.lireInt();
            }


        }
    }while (selectionMenuPrincipal !='3');
    System.out.print(MSG_END_PROGRAM);
}

}
```

and this is the part I'm struggling with:

```
}else if (selectionMenuPrincipal == '2') {
            System.out.print(MSG_PRODUCT_CODE);
            codeProduit = Clavier.lireInt();
            while (codeProduit < 100000 || codeProduit > 999999999) {
                System.out.print(MSG_ERR_CODE);
                codeProduit = Clavier.lireInt();
            }
```

Comment: What exactly does Clavier.lireInt() do? Do you have the source for the Clavier class?

Comment: @WilliamBurnham `Clavier` is French for "keyboard", and `lireInt` is French for "readInt".  So I'm guessing it's a French-language wrapper around the `Scanner` class.

Comment: @OP So right now, this is a "do my homework for me" question, which is off topic here.  Think about what you would do if you actually had a number, and what kinds of maths you would do on it to get the first two digits.

Comment: You can extract the digits of a number by dividing by multiples of 10 and taking the non-decimal part; i.e: to extract 12 from 123 you do 123/10, to extract 1 from 123 you do 123/100, etc

Comment: @JoeC I didn't needed the exact code for my program, I just needed an explanation of how it can be done. Just like Ian did, he gave me the tool to make it myself.

Comment: Writing the code always has been, and always will be, the easy part.  The hard part will always be taking the problem and transforming it into a series of concrete steps that can then be translated into code.  **Programming homework is meant to enhance this skill**, and having other people do it for you defeats its entire purpose.

Comment: Look @JoeC, I'm totally with you on the purpose of the homework, but sometime just a little tip can make a long way in the learning process too. Being stuck on something and not having any help, will not enhance any skill. I've tried pretty much everything I could think of to do it but it was always bugging or was not giving me the output I was looking for. It's my first time codding and I'm working two job while I'm in school full time. So maybe stop trying to make a statement here and start helping people who's just asking for some help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick demonstration of using modulus and division by 10 to build up the model number until you have 2 digits left; then getting the category and product.

```
public class NumberDecomposer {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    decompose(1212345);
    decompose(24123457);
}

private static void decompose(int modelCode) {
    System.out.println("Original modelCode="+modelCode);
    int factor = 1;
    int modelNumber = 0;
    while (modelCode >= 100) {
        int lastDigit = modelCode % 10;
        modelNumber += lastDigit * factor;
        factor *= 10;
        modelCode /= 10;
    }
    int productCode = modelCode % 10;
    int category = modelCode / 10;
    System.out.printf("Category=%d; Product=%d; Model number=%d\n", category, productCode, modelNumber);
}

}
```

Here is the output of two examples:

```
Original modelCode=1212345
Category=1; Product=2; Model number=12345

Original modelCode=24123457
Category=2; Product=4; Model number=123457
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @Ian Mc, that's exactly what I needed to understand. cheers mate!